# Upsert in Meteor - selector troubles

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have some code:

```
Entrants.upsert({
    // selector
    race_id: entrant.race_id,
    eventbrite: {
        entrant_id: parseInt(entrant.eventbrite.entrant_id)
    }
}, {
    //modifier
    $set: entrant
},
function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        var name = entrant.first_name + " " + entrant.last_name;
        console.log("Problem with " + name + ": " + error);
    }
    console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
}
)
```

Now the issue is with the selector, specifically

```
eventbrite: {
    entrant_id: parseInt(entrant.eventbrite.entrant_id)
}
```

I can't seem to search in child nodes, therefore the document is not found. If I change it to

```
"eventbrite.entrant_id": parseInt(entrant.eventbrite.entrant_id)
```

I get an error: `MongoError: The dotted field 'eventbrite.entrant_id' in 'eventbrite.entrant_id' is not valid for storage.`

I'm doing something simple wrong, can anyone point it out?

EDIT: upserting with this selector `"eventbrite.entrantId": parseInt(entrant.eventbrite.entrantId)` works if the document already exists - the document is upserted (updated). However if the document doesn't exist it errors `MongoError: The dotted field 'eventbrite.entrantId' in 'eventbrite.entrantId' is not valid for storage`. It works fine if it's not a nested document. Bug in meteor?

Comment: Can you show us your document schema and some sample documents with data?

Comment: I'm having the same issue when trying to use a nested int value as the selector. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Seems Meteor 1.2 will have a [fix](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/e02bf0fb30ed67e4f45417986a548b04de802e1d) for it.